# Vue 2 - Email Misspelled - Typings cannot be exported

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, typescript-typings

We have a vue 2 project with typescript. We have recently started using EmailMisspelled. When installing the packages (npm install) and then running the project, it will throw the following errors:

```
    ERROR in C:/Git/BookingForms/node_modules/email-misspelled/lib/index.d.ts(3,104):
3:104 Cannot find name 'from'.
    1 | export * from "./domains";
    2 | import { emailMisspelled } from "./emailMisspelled";
  > 3 | export type { DomainList, Result, EmailMisspelled, EmailMisspelledConfig, EmailMisspelledConstructor } from "./typings";
      |                                                                                                        ^
    4 | export default emailMisspelled;
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 80",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.4.3",
    "crypto-ts": "^1.0.2",
    "email-misspelled": "3.4.1",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "v-mask": "^2.2.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.7.4",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^8.1.5",
    "vue-google-autocomplete": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-ics": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-phone-number-input": "^1.1.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "watchpack": "2.4.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.3"
  }
}
```

I have checked and the typing is actually exporting the interfaces:
content of node_modules/email-misspelled/typings/index.ds.t:

index.d.ts

```
export interface Result {
    /** Suggested domain */
    suggest: string;
    /** Corrected email */
    corrected: string;
    /** Number correction needed */
    misspelledCount: number;
    /** Original email */
    original: string;
}
export interface EmailMisspelled {
    (email: string): Result[];
}
export interface EmailMisspelledConfig {
    /** Maximum length difference between strings; Default: 2 */
    lengthDiffMax?: number;
    /** Number of misspelled error allowed; Default: 2 */
    maxMisspelled?: number;
    /** List of email domain to compare */
    domains: string[];
}
export interface EmailMisspelledConstructor {
    (config: {
        /** Maximum length difference between strings; Default: 2 */
        lengthDiffMax?: number;
        /** Number of misspelled error allowed; Default: 2 */
        maxMisspelled?: number;
        /** List of email domain to compare */
        domains: string[];
    }): EmailMisspelled;
}
```

And here is the actual line in node_modules/email-misspelled/lib/index.t.s:

```
export * from "./domains";
import { emailMisspelled } from "./emailMisspelled";
export type { DomainList, Result, EmailMisspelled, EmailMisspelledConfig, EmailMisspelledConstructor } from "./typings";
export default emailMisspelled;
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `npm install -g typescript` and also bumping the package cersion to the latest?

Comment: @EspressoCode thanks tried that, but didn't solve the issue.